# Excel always change my data to date when copy a html sheet to it

Tags: excel, date, format

I copy a sheet from html page.Because I need the sheet structure,the "paste as text" selection is no use here.

The data will be like this

```
2/3               3/4
1012/2332         332/665
```

when paste to excel

```
2/3/2012          3/4/2012
1012/2332         332/665
```

the data cannot be parsed to date form is safe while those which can will be changed and cannot be changed back in format cell.

How to disable this feature of excel,really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an obnoxious problem. Have you tried setting the cell format to `Text` before pasting *as* text? this works for me in 2003. I'm afraid simply doing one or the other is not enough, and the order is important.

If this works (and you need to do this frequently or regularly), you can set up a custom macro (e.g. CTRL-SHIFT-P, etc.) to set the format and do the paste all in one motion.

**EDIT:**

For the record, here is what the different paste methods produced for "2/3":

```
Paste (normal)          3-Feb
TXT Format->Paste       3-Feb
Paste->TXT Format       40942
Paste UNI               3-Feb
*TXT Format->Paste UNI  2/3
Paste UNI->TXT Format   40942
Paste TXT               3-Feb
*TXT Format->Paste TXT  2/3
Paste TXT->TXT Formar   40942
```

Comment: Unfortunatley Excel will try to guess the data type if you leave the cell formatting as general.

Comment: nope,if pasting as text,the structure of the html sheet is lost,all you pasted are several lines of plain text each in only one cell.This do keeps the text unchanged but lost the sheet organization which need more work to reform them.

Comment: @Oyss Meaning, you have multiple values in one cell? If that's the case, does using the text-to-columns function work?

Answer (score 0):

Up until recently (2/27/2013) the Excel data import of the bank account text file information handled the date field of the text file correctly.  It isn't clear to me why this changed, but it lead to my looking here for a solution.

I'd like to propose to you a different solution than above...

1. copy the offending dates to a separate excel sheet
2. use the Mid function ( mid(string, start, number of chars) to extract each date component to 
   a separate column in the same row  (Look at columns B, C, and D
3. in the next column use the Date function ( date(yr, month, day) to convert the date components
   from the prior three columns into something excel will deign to recognize as a date (remember, 
   computers are basically stupid, and Microsoft programs are about the contrariest things on the 
   planet!)
4. PASTE SPECIAL the values from your date column back to your worksheet
   VOILA!  You have fixed a problem that you should NEVER have had in the first place.

I tried to paste the spreadsheet here (and also by hand typing, but this display collapses repeating characters.  Suffice to say it looks like this...

02/27/2013 02 27 2013 02/27/2013
original   mm dd yyyy value ms recognizes as a date which you can paste by value back to spreadsheet

the formulas for those not familiar with Excel...
un-date from worksheet in column at (excel sees as a string...not a number!)
for month: mid(a1,1,2)  (take the thing in column a1, start at the 1st character, and grab two chars)
for day:   mid(a1,4, 2) (take the same thing from column a1, grab the two chars starting at the 4th)
for year:  mid(a1,7,4)  ...
making it a date:  you now have month in column b1, day in column c1, and year in column d1, so
in column e1 you say: date(d1, b1, c1), and then you see the same date as shown in column a1, however, this will now be recognized by Excel as a date!  Copy this and PASTE SPECIAL>Value to the column in your original worksheet and it will respond.

I had looked in the original column for a ' character which denotes treat this value as text only, but I hadn't found one.  I do not know why Excel has become pesky like this, but I have come to expect this type of frustrating and annoying behavior from Microsoft programs.  Yes, I do still buy the darn things, but often choose open source code when I can because of these "features".

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem and found a really good solution.  Here are my steps:

1. Copy and paste so that you can work out the area to be selected.
2. Delete the contents of the cells
3. Change the formatting to TEXT
4. re-paste but use the paste button in the menu bar and choose 'Match Destination formatting'.

This works like a dream! :)